# error in code - averageOfMarks = sum(sumOfMarks)/5 TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Tags: python

Having trouble understanding how to fix the errors in this code, I am asked to input the results of 5 subjects and get the print the sum and average marks

```py
#enter marks of 5 subjects 
print("please enter your 5 marks below")

#read 5 inputs
mark1 = int(input("enter mark 1: "))
mark2 = int(input("enter mark 2: "))
mark3 = int(input("enter mark 3: "))
mark4 = int(input("enter mark 4: "))
mark5 = int(input("enter mark 5: "))

#create array/list with five marks
marksList = [mark1, mark2, mark3, mark4, mark5]

#print the array/list
print(marksList)

#calculate the sum and average
sumOfMarks = sum(marksList)
averageOfMarks = sum(sumOfMarks)/5

#display results
print("The sum of your marks is: "+str(sumOfMarks))
print("The average of your marks is: "+str(averageOfMarks))
```

Comment: `averageOfMarks = sumOfMarks/5`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is just a basic typo and logic error
what you did is this

```
sumOfMarks = sum(marksList)

averageOfMarks = sum(sumOfMarks)/5
```

what you have to do is

```
sumOfMarks = sum(marksList)

averageOfMarks = sumOfMarks/5
```

just remove the `sum` you were using with `sumOfmarks`

Answer (score 0):

`sum` requires an iterable.
`sumOfMarks` is an int.

If you already did the summation calculation, just do

```py
averageOfMarks = sumOfMarks/5
```

If you want to do the calculation in 1 step, with more robustness:

```py
averageOfMarks = sum(marksList)/len(marksList)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sum always expects an iterable you are trying to calculate already an output of sum, which is an integer value, you can just give:

averageOfMarks = sumOfMarks/5